# Lista vacia en React

Tags: reactjs

Necesito guardar varios objetos en una lista vacia a través del evento del botón para despues agregarlo en el localstorage. Pero el problema es que al hacer el primer clic en el botón para guardar los datos, se guarda el estado vacío y no se actualiza con los datos puestos antes del evento del botón, al hacer el segundo clic ahí si se guarda, es como si estuviera un clic por detrás del siguiente.

```
const ToDo = (props) => {
  const fecha_filtro = props.fecha_filtro;
  const [titulo, setTitulo] = useState("");
  const [tarea, setTarea] = useState("");
  const [listaTareas, setListaTareas] = useState([]);

  const hanbleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const random = Math.random()
      setListaTareas([ 
        {
          id: random,
          fecha_filtro: fecha_filtro,
          titulo: titulo,
          tarea: tarea,
          completado: false,
        },
       ...listaTareas 
      ]);
      console.log(listaTareas)
  };

  return (
    <>
        <i>Estas en el dia {fecha_filtro} para agendar una tarea</i>
        <input
          name="titulo"
          placeholder="Titulo de la tarea"
          onChange={(e) => setTitulo(e.target.value)}
        ></input>
        <textarea
          name="tarea"
          placeholder="Descipcion de la tarea"
          onChange={(e) =>  setTarea(e.target.value)}
        ></textarea>
        <button onClick={(e) => hanbleSubmit(e)}>Save</button>
    </>
  );
};

export default ToDo;
```

Comment: ¿En qué momento intentas guardar los datos en el `localStorage`?

Comment: Donde esta el console.log ahi pongo `localStorage.setItem(`${fecha_filtro}`, JSON.stringify(listaTareas));`. Puse el console para que se entienda en el ejemplo pero el problema es donde poner esa línea

Comment: ¿Y por qué la necesidad de usar un estado para guardar ese objeto en `localStorage`? Te recomiendo que en vez de guardar los datos en el estado `listaTareas`, crees un nuevo objeto con esos mismos datos y luego lo guardes en `localStorage`. Si eso arregla tu problema, lo agregaré como respuesta dando más detalles de lo que creo que produce tu error.

Answer (score 0):

Ejecute tu codigo, si se esta guardando la primera vez, te recomiendo la extencion para el navegado react develpers tools, con esto puedes ver en tiempo real lo que se guarda en el state conmo los inputs entre otras cosas.

Lo que pasa es por el funcionamiento interno de javascript, se van ejecutando el codigo de forma sincrona, primero el  e.preventDefault() depsues const random = Math.random() despues setListaTareas y despues cuando aun no se han guradado los valores en el state el console.log

en el segundo click en realidad estas viendo el resultado del clik anterior por esto te recomiendo react developer tools

Comment: Gracias por el dato de la extensión, veo que efectivamente se guarda. Pero, entonces como puedo hacer para ejecutarlo de forma asíncrona?. Como hacer para que al primer clic aparezcan los datos que tienen que aparecer?

Comment: saca el log por fuera de la función. así verás el valor del estado actual que puedes ver en el renderizado